# Let $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}f(t)dt$ Prove $f_n(x)$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}f(t)dt$ for $x \in [0,1]$ where $f : [-1,2] \to \mathbb{R} $ is a continuous function.

Prove for all $n > 1$ that $fn(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$

I know I need to use the FTC here. So we have:

As $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[-1,2]$ there exists $F(x)$ such that $F(x) = \int_{-1}^x f(t)dt$ and $F$ is uniformly continuous over the same interval. Moreover $F'(x) = f(x), \forall x \in (-1,2)$

My thinking is that as $f$ is continuous over $[0-1/n, 1 + 1/n], \forall n \ge 1$.

We can set $F_n(x) = \int_{x - 1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt, \forall x \in [0,1]$ then $\frac{n}{2}F_n(x) = \frac{n}{2}\int_{x - 1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt$ and by the FTC we get $\frac{n}{2}F_n'(x) = \frac{n}{2}f(x)$ for all $x \in (0-1/n,1+1/n)$

And if $1 < n < \infty $ then $[0,1] \subset (0-1/n, 1+1/n)$ we get the desired result that $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{2}F_n(x)$ is differentiable over $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus in a more direct way. Let $0 < \lvert h\rvert < 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $x\in [0, 1]$. Then, \begin{align*} \frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(h)}{h} &= \frac{n}{2h}\left[\int_{x+h-1/n}^{x+h+1/n} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right] \\ &= \frac{n}{2h}\left[\int_{x+1/n}^{x+h+1/n} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{x-1/n}^{x+h-1/n} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right] \end{align*} so $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(h)}{h} = \frac{n}{2}[f(x+1/n)-f(x-1/n)]$$ by the FTC. Therefore, $f_n'(x) = \frac{n}{2}[f(x+1/n)-f(x-1/n)]$ for $x\in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $x\in [0,1] $,

$$-1\le x-1/n <x+1/n\le 2$$

and

$$f_n (x )=\frac {n}{2}\Bigl(F (x+\frac {1}{n})-F (x-\frac {1}{n}) \Bigr)$$

use chain rule with $F'=f $.

Comment: Why the chain rule? would I not just use the sum rule and constant multiple rule.